# Continue Springboot startup if Ignite fails connection

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, ignite, azure-aks

I have a springboot microservice application, deployed as docker image in a Kubernetes cluster.
This microservice is (also) an Ignite Client.
If for some reason Ignite Bean fails the startup (for example because there is no Ingnite Server service), the overall application is not able to startup.

I would like to make not mandatory the complete startup of Ignite Bean, so my service can be up & running, even if it cannot use Ignite.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add some code that you try to implement.... then only able to understood your problem

Comment: not enough information. share your deployment manifest and output of `kubectl get pods -o wide` command

Comment: Did you try making this bean lazily-initialized?